# UserMixin breaks mySQL-connector

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

User model is committing to the database as intended if it's not inheriting from UserMixin, but when I add UserMixin to the user model, I got an error from mySQLConnector stating `_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type User cannot be converted`.

I've tried to find alternatives to MySQLConnector but MySQLConnector does the trick besides this one process. I do not want to downgrade to python 2.x. Are there any solutions?

UPDATE: I've been playing around and it seems mySQLConnector doesn't like anything with methods.. it fails when there's even a single method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs when SQLConnector tries to put a method in the database: it fails

To fix this, split the User class into two seperate Classes: UserData and User. In user data, put all the attributes you want to commit to the database. then, in the User class, inherit from both UserMixin and UserData. When committing to database, commit UserData instead of User. When using methods from flask_login, cast a UserData object as a User object. everything then works as intended.